# trouble displaying Persian letters in CSV file

Tags: oracle-apex

In Oracle APEX, I have trouble displaying Persian letters when outputting a report as a CSV file, and Persian letters are displayed as question marks. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

a few questions, if you don't mind ...
what is your database character set ...?
How's Automatic CSV Encoding set in your application (Shared Components > Application Definition Attributes > Globalization)

changing "Application primary language" to "Persian " here ((Shared Components > Application Definition Attributes > Globalization))